# (logn)^(logn) = n^(log10+logn). WHY?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

I'm comparing $f(n)$: `O(logn^logn)` vs. $g(n)$: `O(n/logn)`.

I multiplied `logn` to both sides, then it will be `logn^(1+logn)` vs `n`.

Question: what do we do here next to compare two functions?

---

My solution for textbook says,

$f(n)$ is $n^{\log\log n}$ , so $f(n)$ is superior to $g(n)$. $\leftarrow$ I don't understand why it's $n^{\log\log n}$.

$\leftarrow$ I guess $n^{\log\log n}$ is $n^{\log 10+\log n}$.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) to format your posts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\log(n)^{\log(n)} = \left ( b^{\log(\log(n))} \right )^{\log(n)}=(b^{\log(n)})^{\log(\log(n))}=n^{\log(\log(n))}$$

assuming the log is base $b$. Since $\log(\log(n))$ is growing, this grows faster than just $n$ which has a fixed exponent.

Comment: I don't understand why logn is equivalent to b^log(logn(n)). Can you illustrate it on answer?

Answer (score 2):

Taking the logarithm of both $\log n^{\log n}$ and $n^{\log \log n}$, we have
$$
\log\left(\log n ^{\log n}\right) = \log n \cdot \log\log n
$$
and
$$
\log\left( n^{\log\log n}\right) = \log\log n \cdot \log n
$$
Therefore,
$$
\log n ^{\log n} = n^{\log \log n}
$$

Answer (score 1):

We need to check the equality:
$$
(\log n)^{\log n} = n^{\log \log n} \tag{1}
$$

Let $n=e^a>1$, then $\log n = a$, and it is easy to see that both sides of $(1)$ are equal to $a^a$:
$$
(\log n)^{\log n}=a^a \quad\mbox{ and } \quad n^{\log \log n} =e^{a\log a}=a^a.
$$